# How strict Firestore Rules have to be?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Can I trust the data that are coming in the Firestore, or do I have to check everything and absolutely not trust the incoming data, because client can fake everything?

For example, can client fake uid, email and display name?

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(state.user.uid).collection("friendRequests").doc(payload.uid).set({
  uid: payload.uid,
  email: payload.email,
  displayName: payload.displayName
});
```

Firestore rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /users/{userId}/friendRequests/{friendId} {
      allow create: if userId == request.auth.uid
      && friendId != request.auth.uid
      && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/friends/$(friendId))
      && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/friendRequests/$(friendId))
      && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(friendId)/friends/$(request.auth.uid))
      && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(friendId)/friendRequests/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
  }
}
```

Set of rules is already quite big and I didn't even check yet if the data structure is valid and if friend uid exists.

Answer (score 0):

The `request.auth` in your security rules is populated by Firebase Authentication. That means that the user triggering the rules must have signed in with Firebase Authentication, and that the profile in `request.auth` is belonging to the user that signed in.

The only way someone can hijack that process is if they get access to the administrative credentials for your project. With that they can generate any tokens they want. But if this happen, they can already access your database without restrictions, so the additional step of forging a token is rather useless.

Of course when using a social provider (Facebook, Github, Google, etc) users can set whatever display name they want. So you typically should not depend on that being valid, beyond using it to display a name for each user.